# Can a Python package name (on pypi) contain an diaeresis/"umlaut"?

Tags: python, unicode, pip, easy-install, pypi

Can a Python package name contain an umlaut, i.e. "ä", "ü" or "ö"? Are there limitations and differences (encoding, OS, Python 2 vs 3)?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 2.x does not allow any characters other than letters, numbers, and underscores.

Python 3.x supports far more characters, including the umlaut and other letters with diaereses. However, it is not recommended to use special characters in your identifier names. This could make it difficult for other users to use your package or read your identifier name.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/

https://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/home/loewis/table-3131.html

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer speaks of "identifier names". In fact, I've personally tested using some fun Unicode (Japanese words etc.) as local module names; Python's import system (as of version 3.10) seems to handle them just fine.

However, *distribution package* names on PyPI are subject to [much more restrictive normalization rules](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/name-normalization/) per PyPA standards:

> #### Valid non-normalized names
>
> A valid name consists only of ASCII letters and numbers, period, underscore and hyphen. It must start and
> end with a letter or number. This means that valid project names are
> limited to those which match the following regex (run with
> `re.IGNORECASE`):
>
> ```
> ^([A-Z0-9]|[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9._-]*[A-Z0-9])$
> ```